# Checking two variables for the same conditions

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to check different variables against the same limit. How can I put this elegantly?

Please don't say `if(i>8 && j>8)`. I know that, but I have more conditions on both variables like

```
if(i,j>8 || i,j<0)
```

How to go about that? Do I have to write 4 conditions?

Comment: Like you did. No other way.

Comment: Write a new language...

Comment: You can write special function that will return boolean, but that will much more hard to read.

Comment: Do you have many variables that need to be checked for some properties or do you have many properties two variables have to be checked for? In both cases, if many is 2, there won't be an easier-to-read way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write all conditions. The only other alternative would be to use alot of else-if, which I wouldn't recomend.

If you REALLY feel like hiding the condition logic you could make a function that does it (I guess to make the code more readable?), something like this:

```
bool checkTheValues(int i, int j, int k /*etc*/)
{
    if((i>8&&j>8)||j<i /*or whatever*/)
        return true
    return false;
}
```

and then:

```
if(checkTheValues(i, j, k))
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define Less(i, j, n) (i<n && j<n)
#define More(i, j, n) (i>n && j>n)

int main()
{
   if(More(i, j, 8) || Less(i, j, 0))
      // Do stuff
}
```

You can extrapolate the above example to fit whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

use boost macro

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>

#define F(r, data, i, elem) BOOST_PP_IF(i, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, data), ) (elem BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, data))
#define all(cond, ...) (BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(F, (&&, cond) , BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__)) ))

if(all(>8, i, j) || all(<0, i, j))//expand to if(( (i  >8) && (j  >8)  ) || ( (i  <0) && (j  <0)  ))
```